# Suggestion to rename the tag "cocos2d-iphone" to "cocos2d-ios"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The tag [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) isn't specific to development on the iPhone. It is specific to iOS development, using Cocos2d and it even states that in the tag wiki.

Therefore, I recommend renaming this tag to [cocos2d-ios](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-ios).  This suggestion is also supported by the fact that if you check out the [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) wiki, you will see that the other Cocos2d tags relate to other frameworks or architectures are not to specific devices that that Cocos2d can run on.

Furthermore, since all questions regarding [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) also directly related to the iPod Touch and iPad, I think this tag should be renamed with a more generalized meaning.

Comment: I just noticed that this tag also exists on the game development site.  I assume this is the type of change that should be made across stackexchange, but I think if this is made on stackoverflow, the update could trickle across the other sites that have this tag.  There is no reason why this should ever be a tag specific to iphone.

Comment: Tags are site-specific, not network-wide.  Any retagging or renaming would have to be done on each site.